# Lightbox image is too small (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, lightbox

I have uploaded an image into a wordpress website and when i enable open in lightbox the image actually shrinks to about a 200x200px square. the original file is much larger and im wondering if there is a way to enable the lightbox to display the larger image (or at least not shrink the image once it is opened in a lightbox)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the image link the lightbox was referencing had dimensions in the url, going to the media tab and taking the image location itself and pasting it in fixed the issue.